# Getting commits above HEAD

Tags: java, intellij-plugin

It might be some kind of repetitive question, but I can't seem to find a proper solution. I'm getting a list of commits using git4idea.history.GitHistoryUtils.history(). In case one of the lower revisions (in a commit tree) is checked out, this commit becomes first in a resulting list and all of the above get ignored.

Is there a way to grab a full list of commits just like the IDEA itself does it when HEAD is lower on the list, but Vcs Log window shows all the commits from previously checked out branch (in my case 'master')?

Thank you!

Comment: I am having some trouble understanding what you're trying to do. You want to see the history for more recent commits while you have a previous commit checked out?

Comment: Yes. Having 20 commits in a branch and checking out a commit right in the middle of the list makes GitHistoryUtils.history() return only 10 commits instead of all 20. So I'm curious if there's a way to retrieve everything.

Comment: Answered below because too long for a comment

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: you cannot get it a list of all commits to date while having an older commit checked out because that is not how HEAD works.

What happens in git when you checkout a previous commit? You land in a state called "detached HEAD". It's called that because HEAD (which is a pointer to the state of the code repo on the latest commit) is detached from the normal flow. This is why you no longer see the newer commits. You have requested for HEAD to become frozen, pointing at a certain point in time. Also if you make changes while in detached HEAD and commit them, they will not carry through to the branch.

So instead of asking “how can I get a list of all commits in this window even though I’m on an earlier checkout” you should go back to the reason you want that, the goal you are trying to achieve, and find another way to achieve that.

What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: A user is checking out different commits using buttons (back and forward) to see the content of the plugin window (text of a file) change accordingly. I need to somehow pre-fetch the list of commits in a branch. What I was trying to do earlier is to grab all of them at project launch with project/application service, but I kept getting null when trying to access git repositories. They seem to not become available at this point. And another case is when the project opens already with a detached HEAD and I can't grab the whole history. So I'm trying to think of ways how do I go about that...

Comment: If your use case is only to see the content of a text or file, maybe you could use IntelliJ''s "Git > Compare to ..." as a basis and then only pass on the part that is from the commit you're comparing to?
And when you already open with detached HEAD and then you need to show the list of full commits I think you can either 1. already store the list of commits from when you're still in normal flow or 2. somehow open the full branch in a 2nd context to see the list there or 3. checkout detached HEAD to a new branch to switch between that and the full branch (and clean up new branch after)